# How to convert Numbers in to Million in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have below mentioned big data frame:

```
S.NO   T1    T2       T3     T4
 1     12    100000   2      250000
 2     5     1000000  8      300000
 3     10    50000    12     400000
 4     1     80000    3      175000
```

I want to convert `T2` and `T4` in Millions (i.e Value of `T1` and `T2` divided by 1000000)

Output:

```
S.NO   T1    T2       T3     T4
 1     12    0.1      2      0.25
 2     5     1        8      0.3
 3     10    0.05     12     0.4
 4     1     0.08     3      0.175
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can subset the columns of the dataset, divide by 1e6, and update the dataset columns

```
df1[c("T2", "T4")] <- df1[c("T2", "T4")]/1e6
```